# Remove the word class and its content inside <img> tag

Tags: regex

I want to remove the word class and its content and retain other tags without affecting the words inside the paragraph:

```
<p class="Firstpara"><i>Let S be a regular surface, p</i> ∈ <i>S, and <span class="inline"/><img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/> = <img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/><sub>ϵ</sub></i>(<i>p</i>) <i>a normal neighborhood of p. Then every geodesic segment in <img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/> beginning at p is uniquely minimizing.</i></p>
```

I tried to use this regex and perform it to notepad++:

Find what :

```
(<img.*)(class=".*?")(.*?/>)
```

Replace with :

```
$1$3
```

but it failed to retain the words inside the paragraph.

Comment: Only RegEx Sir.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this, though.  What if there's a newline inside the tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(<img[^\/]*?)class="[^"]*"(.*?\/>)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/EUsoqe/5)

```js
const regex = /(<img[^\/]*?)class="[^"]*"(.*?\/>)/g;
const str = `<p class="Firstpara"><i>Let S be a regular surface, p</i> ∈ <i>S, and <span class="inline"/><img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/> = <img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/><sub>ϵ</sub></i>(<i>p</i>) <i>a normal neighborhood of p. Then every geodesic segment in <img alt="" class="img_Owthpnkbckgrnd_jpg_w23h25_v-10px" src="../Images/img_Owthpnkbckgrnd.jpg" style=""/> beginning at p is uniquely minimizing.</i></p>`;
const subst = `$1$2`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Maverick for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex in notepad++:

Find:

```
(<p.*<img.*?)class=".*?"(.*?/p>)
```

Replace:

```
$1$2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rUDMeD/5